# Set variable based on @State properties

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-state

Inside my View struct, I have the following `@State` properties:

```
@State private var email = ""
@State private var password = ""
```

And multiple times in the View `body` I repeat this code to check whether the login button should be disabled:

```
email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty
```

From what I have tried, trying to set `isDisabled` within the View `body` gives:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Is there a way I can add a variable within the View struct like `isDisabled` so I don't need to repeat this logic?

Comment: Don't you want to put it into computed property?

Comment: @Asperi Yep, that's it! For some reason I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi), all I needed was a Computed Property:

```
private var isDisabled: Bool {
    email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty
}
```